# JavaScript, What have I done wrong?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So, I've been messing around with this bit of code which I will eventually be moving into my mute command. I can't seem to figure out what is wrong with this.

```
if(args[0].length >= 4) {
  return msg.reply("Please use abbreviated time formats! **m**, **h**, **d**, **w**")
}
var data = args[0]
if(args[0].length = 3) {
  data = data.substr(0, 2) + " " + data.substr(2, 3);
  msg.channel.send(data);
}
else if(data.length = 2) {
  data = data.substr(0, 1) + " " + data.substr(1, 2);
  msg.channel.send(data);
  msg.channel.send("test")
}
```

Basically, the first part where it sends a message if the length is 4 characters or more works. But, no matter how many characters below 4 are, it will always only run the `if(args[0].length =3)` part of the code. I've been trying to figure it out for the past hour and I don't seem to know what is wrong with it. I must be blind or something.

Comment: You need to use double equal signs `if(args[0].length == 3)`

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I tried that, that doesn't fix it.

Comment: If it does not solve, then there’s another problem. But the usage of single equal sign in this case is not correct and will probably throw exception.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz I fixed it, thanks. I realized I only put 3 equal signs for one of them instead of both.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz Also, I'm aware that using single equal signs doesn't work. But it was the only solution I had at the time that semi-worked when I first posted my question.

Comment: @Not_A_Dev I'm sorry to reply here, but you removed your Java question. Why ? Also, there is multiple way to do what you want. There is API and event. What you want to do make sens, but not how you do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an attempted assignment statement:

```
if(args[0].length = 3) {
```

The evaluation of that expression is not only an unattended assignment, but it always evaluates to `3` which means it will always be true.  That's why this clause always runs regardless of the length of your argument.

This is probably what you meant (comparison, not assignment):

```
if(args[0].length == 3) {
```

And even better:

```
if(args[0].length === 3) {
```

Same mistake needs a correction for the `else if(data.length = 2) {` clause as well.

Comment: I use 3 equal signs for stuff like that. But I just realized that when I was testing it, I only put 3 equal signs for the if(args[0].length = 3) one and not both. It would probably help if I made sure I did it for both

Comment: Also, not all your statements have semicolons at the end.

Comment: Doesn't matter. I haven't been using semi-colons in VSCode since 6 months ago and it works fine.

Comment: But sometimes I accidentally put them since I'm used to coding spigot plugins in Intellij

Comment: @Not_A_Dev - sure it works fine.  Until the day you type something more sophisticated and an unintended side-effect gets created as a result of another type and two lines get interpreted as a single statement. Consider taking up Typescript - it catches typos faster than you can post to Stackoverflow for help.

Comment: You don't need semi-colons in vscode..

Comment: @Not_A_Dev - I think what you are saying is that *"Visual Studio Code, an IDE editor, doesn't flag the code as an error while you type, so therefore the program must be correct"*.  That would not be an accurate statement. Google for `Javascript semicolon insertion` to understand the side effects of using it incorrectly.  Strict mode and typescript will require it so you don't accidently code an error.  Read this: https://dev.to/adriennemiller/semicolons-in-javascript-to-use-or-not-to-use-2nli

Comment: I haven't been using them, and everything works as I want it to, so it's fine.

Comment: @Not_A_Dev - Just curious, but are you trolling me?  I participate in StackOverflow not to give out answers and debug code, but to also make others better programmers. If you can't at least *acknowledge* some of the simplest advice on programming fundamentals, you'll never get past the moniker that you are currently using.

Comment: I'm not trolling, no. But what you clearly don't understand is that you don't need semi-colons with VSCode. You won't get errors, everything works fine. Maybe you just don't understand that but maybe you should load up VSCode and try using javascript without semi-colons. And I know how to use semi-colons as I've taken 5 years' worth of programming classes but I'd rather not use them if I have the opportunity not to.

Comment: And we're done.

Comment: I know how to program. I'm not stupid. You helped me with ONE thing that I forgot to check for. You're not making me a "better programmer" if I already know how to program, like?

Answer (score 2):

A single `=` is assign a value to a variable.

```
const name = 'John'
let age = 30
```

Double `=` is a comparison operator. It will transform the value to the same type before comparison.

```
console.log('1' == 1) // true
```

Triple `=` does the same thing but it won't transform the type. So the result is more accuracy.

```
console.log('1' === 1) // false
```

In most circumstances, stick with the triple `=`.